# Azure Search - OrderBy filterable field then by distance

Tags: search, azure, azure-cognitive-search

I'm trying to cater for the following example with Azure Search.
Given the following index schema:

```
{
  "name": "mySchema",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "Id",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "key": true,
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": false,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "suggestions": false
    },
    {
      "name": "StateId",
      "type": "Edm.Int32",
      "key": false,
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "suggestions": false
    },
    {
      "name": "Location",
      "type": "Edm.GeographyPoint",
      "key": false,
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "facetable": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "suggestions": false
    },
  ],
}
```

I want to be able to order my results firstly on the `StateId` field, and *then* by the distance from a given lat/long location.

I realise that I am able to achieve the first part by using a `$filter= StateId eq x` component when querying. However, I do want to still receive results (with a lower score) that are not in the provided StateId, but are of a given distance away from a provided location.

I recognise also, that this looks like it should be able to be achieved by a custom Scoring Profile. I would expect by using a Scoring Profile, I'd be able to return something like this:

```
[
  {
    "@search.score":100.0,
    "Id":"111",
    "StateId":"123",
    "Location": {"type": "Point details...."},
  },
  {
    "@search.score":100.0,
    "Id":"222",
    "StateId":"123",
    "Location": {"type": "Point details...."},
  },
  {
    "@search.score":50.0,
    "Id":"333",
    "StateId":"789",
    "Location": {"type": "Point details...."},
  }
]
```

However, I am not able to search on the `StateId` field, as this is an `Edm.Int32` value, so I do not believe using a Scoring Profile would be a viable solution.

Anyone come across a similar scenario?

**EDIT:**

Trying to explain just a bit further - if I were to explain this in Psuedo-SQL, this is basically the case I'm trying to handle

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN StateId = @StateId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC, Location
```

Comment: A thought I've had regarding this is to add an additional, searchable field called something like "StateIdGuid", and using a scoring profile to match on this value.

Comment: Where your data has been stored, are you using Azure Table Storage?

Comment: This is using Azure Search - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/search/

Comment: SQL Azure V12 now supports full-text search if in case  you want to use that: http://www.sqlindepth.com/full-text-search-in-sql-azure/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't currently support modeling this scenario with scoring profiles. This has come up multiple times though, so it's something we'd like to add.

In the meanwhile, one thing you can do as a work-around is to add the StateId value to one of the searchable fields (e.g. just append it at the end of the text). Then during search include the state id as part of the search string, which should skew results towards those documents that match the state id (or that are a very good match without it, which might be good relevance anyway depending on the case).

During display, if you show this text field you'd have to strip out the state id from the end of the string (or use a different field).

Comment: Thanks for the response. This isn't really a useful workaround for me though. I think I'm consigned to doing 2 queries. The first to get where `StateId eq 123`, the second, where `StateId ne 123 AND geo.distance(location, ...`